# Debugging "Attempting to use an MPI routine after finalizing MPI"

Tags: mpi, ms-mpi

Is there an easy way to get at "Attempting to use an MPI routine after finalizing MPI"? It is for sure being called by a logging message, possibly in a destructor, but I can't find the call.

Comment: Yeah it was a destructor. Don't do things in destructors fam

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same error as you, but I do not have any destructores in my c program. Any ideas?

Comment: Try wrapping your calls to MPI functions and `cout`ing em if you're using raw MPI. Or write a `boost::mpi` wrapper, that saved me SO MUCH time.

Comment: Well, I did that before. Everything seems to be fine till the wrapper for mpi_finalize() returns. But afterwards, I am getting these errors.

Comment: You sure it's not process 1 ending while process 2 is still doing something?

Comment: Yeah, I have a barrier right before the mpi_finalize().

Comment: Probably a pending listen or send getting cancelled. I'd walk through the processes to see which one is doing it

Comment: If the program is otherwise behaving properly it's usually benign

Comment: Well, I am writing some results to hdf5, but due to this problem, the files could not be opened. They seem to be damaged.